# set_intersection working on integers, but not on chars, even though it's void*

Tags: c, linked-list, set, intersection

I have made a set ADT implementation with set_intersection being one of the functions.

It works well on integers, it goes through both testing systems it shall go through, but when I am trying to use it on chars it isn't working at all. Even though it is made with void * support.

```
set_t *set_intersection(set_t *a, set_t *b) {

    set_t *inter = set_create(a->cmpfunc);

    set_iter_t *iterA = set_createiter(a);
    set_iter_t *iterB;

    void *itemA = set_next(iterA);
    void *itemB;

    while(itemA != NULL) {
        iterB = set_createiter(b);
        itemB = set_next(iterB);
        while (itemB != NULL) {
            if (itemA == itemB) {
                set_add(inter, itemA);
                break;
            }
            itemB = set_next(iterB);
        }
        set_destroyiter(iterB);
        itemA = set_next(iterA);
    }
    set_destroyiter(iterA);


    list_sort(inter->list);
    return inter;
}
```

Using this struct:

```
struct set {
    list_t *list;
    cmpfunc_t cmpfunc;
    int size;
};
```

This is what's happening when trying to do intersect on 2 sets with characters:
[image: Illustration]

Working on integers:
[image: Illustration 2]

The set_t *tmp_x_ is equal to tokenize(spam_item), using the tokenize function.

```
/*
 * Returns the set of (unique) words found in the given file.
 */
static set_t *tokenize(char *filename)
{
    set_t *wordset = set_create(compare_words);
    list_t *wordlist = list_create(compare_words);
    list_iter_t *it;
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        fatal_error("fopen() failed");
    }
    tokenize_file(f, wordlist);

    it = list_createiter(wordlist);
    while (list_hasnext(it)) {
        set_add(wordset, list_next(it));        
    }
    list_destroyiter(it);
    list_destroy(wordlist);
    return wordset;
}
```

My set_union that is working fine:

```
set_t *set_union(set_t *a, set_t *b) {

    set_t *unioner = set_create(a->cmpfunc);

    set_iter_t *iterA = set_createiter(a);
    set_iter_t *iterB = set_createiter(b);

    void *itemA = set_next(iterA);
    void *itemB = set_next(iterB);

    while(itemA != NULL) {
        set_add(unioner, itemA);
        itemA = set_next(iterA);
    }
    while(itemB != NULL) {
        set_add(unioner, itemB);
        itemB = set_next(iterB);
    }

    list_sort(unioner->list);
    return unioner;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to make a set of characters. You are trying to make a set of strings, which is totally different. In C, a string is a pointer to the first character in a 0-terminated sequence of characters, which is a complicated way of saying that in C, a string is a pointer. And two pointers are equal if and only if they point to the same address; two pointers to different addresses which happen to point at the same values are still different pointers.

Note that your set has a `cmpfunc` element. I assume that you were given this data structure as part of your assignment as well, and somewhere it was explained why you might need a function which performs comparisons. You do, because you cannot compare strings the same way you can compare integers.

Comment: So when the tokenize function (which was given to me) is returning a set of (unique) words found in the given file, what do I get?

The thing is that I can use my set_union function which has the same buildup and structure like the set_intersection, just that it does union, but the problem is that set_intersection isn't supposedly working in the same fashion?

Comment: Are you certain there are no repeats in your set_union? I'll bet you will find some -- assuming there are some words which appear in both files.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine with integers, I have tested it with 10 000 numbers. An assert function which tested it have found it to be working. 

I'll post the tokenize and the union function in the mainpost.

Comment: @MrJensenn: Sure, it will work fine with integers because you can compare integers with `==`. You can't compare strings that way. That's why `a->cmpfunc` exists, and why you should *use it*.